# What are the best examples of hybrid apps out there?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, extjs, telerik

I'm writing my thesis on the state of hybrid app development. I would like to see some real world examples of hybrid apps that are in use today, specifically WebView based hybrid apps, so not the Titanium or Xamarin kind.

What apps out there are hybrid? What are the best examples of hybrid apps that make a good argument for hybrid app development? The bigger app the better!

Comment: can you also please upvote my answer ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example I can recommend is [**Tripcase**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sabre.tripcase.android&hl=en). It uses WebKit (PhoneGap), and has a fairly decent UI (for hybrid apps).